# jQuery Mobile does not move to the next page after clicking on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile framework for implementing a mobile website. But when I click on an anchor tag, the page will not be loaded properly and a blank white page will appear as shown in the screenshot.

jQuery and jQuery Mobile Script Tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Screenshot]

My JSP page:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/${cityName}/cakes/c/4"/>">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/sf/assets/img/app/city-home/cake.jpg" alt="cakes" > 
</a>
```

After clicking on the anchor tag, control comes into the controller (Java) and then the controller will return a JSP page; however, a blank page is shown. If I reload the page, then data is showing correctly.

The following line causes control to go to `m-category-page`:

> return "/catalog/m-category-products";

But the first time this page does not have any content, however, after reloading the page, content loaded. After clicking the anchor tag, the next page should be shown with all data.

Comment: try (<a href="<c:url value="/${cityName}/cakes/c/4"/>" data-ajax="false">) -- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-links.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, jQuery Mobile enhances all links tags to make them load pages through ajax; therefore, reducing page load time and "improve performance". See [This](https://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/).

> ajaxEnabled boolean, default: true 
> jQuery Mobile will automatically handle link clicks and form submissions through Ajax, when possible. If false, URL hash listening will be disabled as well, and URLs will load as ordinary HTTP requests.

You can disable this ajax enhancement for **a single tag** by adding `data-ajax="false"` attribute to your links. Also you can disable it **globally** altogether like this:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() {  
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. If you are like my question then please voting up for help to others.